# Close and open a new popup

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am showing my login page as popup using jQuery colorbox as shown below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.colorbox({overlayClose: "false",  width: "500px", height: "400px", opacity: ".8", href: "Login.aspx?", iframe: true });
       });
```

Popup is being shown on page load time of my home page.

This login.aspx page is actually container of a login user control and this usercontrol have a link [newRegistration]. Now on click of [newRegistration] link i need to close the login popup and open new regstration as a new popup. I tried using following code

```
function NewregistrationPopup() {
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
    $.fn.colorbox({ overlayClose: "false", width: "500px", height: "400px", opacity: ".8", href: "NewReg.aspx?", iframe: true });
            return false;
 }
```

I am calling this NewregistrationPopup as follow

```
  ctl = Page.FindControl("ucLogin1").FindControl("lbNewReg"); // LinkButton
        ((LinkButton)ctl).Attributes.Add("onClick", "return NewregistrationPopup();");
```

but it is throwing Object does not exists error. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to close colorbox before opening your new page?  (if so you could use cbox_closed to achieve that).  If you just want the content to change, I would just skip closing it by doing this instead:

```
function NewregistrationPopup() {
    parent.$.fn.colorbox({ overlayClose: "false", width: "500px", height: "400px", opacity: ".8", href: "NewReg.aspx?", iframe: true });
            return false;
 }
```

Comment: yes i nned to close existing popup and open a new popup in a sigle click... i tried using 


function NewregistrationPopup() {     parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();     $.fn.colorbox({ overlayClose: "false", width: "500px", height: "400px", opacity: ".8", href: "NewReg.aspx?", iframe: true });             return false;  } 


is cbox_closed diff from $.fn.colorbox.close().....if yes how to use it acheive my purpose???